# Moodle Invalid function error

Tags: moodle

I'm getting **Invalid function** error on meeting creation page inside moodle. I'm using `moodle version 3.0` and `adobe connect activities plugin` `https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_adobeconnect`

Error/Messages on debug mode:

**Debug info:**

```
Error code: invalidfunction
```

**Stack trace:**

```
line 488 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 135 of /course/modlib.php: call to print_error()
line 274 of /course/modedit.php: call to add_moduleinfo()
```

**Output buffer:**

```
<div class="notifytiny debuggingmessage" data-rel="debugging">error creating meeting
<ul style="text-align: left" data-rel="backtrace">
<li>line 206 of /mod/adobeconnect/lib.php: call to debugging()</li>
<li>line 121 of /course/modlib.php: call to adobeconnect_add_instance()</li>
<li>line 274 of /course/modedit.php: call to add_moduleinfo()</li
</ul></div><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: e in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/lms/course/modlib.php</b> on line <b>132</b><br />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you switch on developer debugging and display the full error message https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Debugging

Comment: @RussellEngland I have added the debug messages in the question.

Comment: So it displays "error creating meeting" on line 206 in https://github.com/remotelearner/moodle-mod_adobeconnect/blob/MOODLE_30_STABLE/lib.php - I would suggest working your way backwards to find out why the result is false.